# mongodb close connection before writing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have this function :

```
module.exports.handler = async event => {
  const client = await MongoClient.connect(
    MONGO_URL,
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
  )
  const db = client.db()

  const cursor = await db.collection('test').find().project({ _id: 1, pro: 1 })

  await cursor.forEach(async doc => {
    if (!doc.elem) {
      return
    }
    const data = doc.elem
    for (const provider of data) {
      const exist = await db
        .collection('public_profiles')
        .findOne({ _id: provider.publicProfileID })
      if (_.isEmpty(provider.publicProfileID) || exist === null) {
        await db
          .collection('test')
          .updateOne(
            { _id: doc._id },
            { $pull: { providers: { publicProfileID: provider.publicProfileID } } }
          )
      }
    }
  })

  await client.close()
  console.log('providers deleted')
}
```

I got this error **MongoError: Topology was destroyed**. I guess because it closes the connection before the updateOne finished but I don't understand why it does that. It seems like the await doesn't wait but I don't get why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
module.exports.handler = async event => {
  const client = await MongoClient.connect(
    MONGO_URL,
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
  )
  const db = client.db()

  const cursor = await db.collection('test').find().project({ _id: 1, pro: 1 })

  while(await cursor.hasNext()){
    const doc = await cursor.next();
    if (!doc.elem) {
      return
    }
    const data = doc.elem
    for (const provider of data) {
      const exist = await db
        .collection('public_profiles')
        .findOne({ _id: provider.publicProfileID })
      if (_.isEmpty(provider.publicProfileID) || exist === null) {
        await db
          .collection('test')
          .updateOne(
            { _id: doc._id },
            { $pull: { providers: { publicProfileID: provider.publicProfileID } } }
          )
      }
    }
  })

  await client.close()
  console.log('providers deleted')
}
```

If this doesn't work `console.log(doc)` might be an issue with the type

if not try this:

```
module.exports.handler = async event => {
  const client = await MongoClient.connect(
    MONGO_URL,
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
  )
  const db = client.db()

  const cursor = await db.collection('test').find().project({ _id: 1, pro: 1 }).toArray()

  for(let i = 0; i < cursor.length; i++){
    const doc = cursor[i];
    if (!doc.elem) {
      return
    }
    const data = doc.elem
    for (const provider of data) {
      const exist = await db
        .collection('public_profiles')
        .findOne({ _id: provider.publicProfileID })
      if (_.isEmpty(provider.publicProfileID) || exist === null) {
        await db
          .collection('test')
          .updateOne(
            { _id: doc._id },
            { $pull: { providers: { publicProfileID: provider.publicProfileID } } }
          )
      }
    }
  })

  await client.close()
  console.log('providers deleted')
}
```

The reason it is closing before looping through all of them is because the `.forEach` is creating many asynchronous function calls and you are not awaiting them (ps: you can't await them even if you tried. These async calls are being created using an anonymous function `async doc => {}` which return promises, but since they are not being awaited they occur after db closes)

Comment: I can't do Promise.all() it says object is not iterable. Also, cursor is not an Array, I can't do .length

Comment: Ahh, i did not know it was not an array. What data type is it? If you convert it to an array the first function I shared should work and the conversion shouldn't increase time complexity nor space.

Comment: It returns a mongo cursor so i don't know if it will work

Comment: Ah, yes I was just reading up on it. Let me edit my response

Comment: Ok, hopefully these changes work. I have not worked with cursors before, so I am just using my understanding of callbacks and promises.

Comment: It works with await cursor.next() but this error poped after some iteration MongoError: cursor id 22661246727 is already in use

Comment: Oh just need to put await to hasNext() too

Comment: Yes. I let you edit your answer with the right await so I can validate it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236381/discussion-between-gajiu-and-hans-krohn).

Answer (score 0):

put extra console.log() for debugging to know at which stage connection closed

```
module.exports.handler = async event => {
  const client = await MongoClient.connect(
    MONGO_URL,
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
  )
  const db = client.db()

  const cursor = await db.collection('test').find().project({ _id: 1, pro: 1 })
  console.log("1")
  await cursor.forEach(async doc => {
    console.log("2")

    if (!doc.elem) {
      return
    }
    const data = doc.elem
    for (const provider of data) {
      console.log("3")

      const exist = await db
        .collection('public_profiles')
        .findOne({ _id: provider.publicProfileID })
      if (_.isEmpty(provider.publicProfileID) || exist === null) {
        await db
          .collection('test')
          .updateOne(
            { _id: doc._id },
            { $pull: { providers: { publicProfileID: provider.publicProfileID } } }
          )
      }
    }
  })
  console.log("4")

  await client.close()
  console.log('providers deleted')
}
```

Comment: I use the debugger and it doesn't seem like the connection is close before my update is over. Another reason why I don't understand the problem

Comment: could you use try and catch to get more logs?